# Circle equation solution

Tags: geometry, circles

Hi I'm stucked with this equation while transforming it into circle equation:

equation is 
$y+\sqrt{x-x^2} = 0$

Here is my solution:
$$y+\sqrt{x-x^2} = 0$$
$$y+\sqrt{-1(x^2-x)} = 0$$
$$y+\sqrt{-1\left(\left(x-\frac 12\right)^2-\frac 14\right)} = 0\qquad (\ )^2$$
$$y^2-\left(x-\frac 12\right)^2+\frac14 = 0\qquad\quad\ \ \frac{-1}4$$
$$y^2-\left(x-\frac 12\right)^2 = \frac{-1}4\qquad\qquad\times(-1)$$
$$\left(x-\frac{ 1}2\right)^2 - y^2 = \frac 14$$

According to Wolframalpha original equation is half-circle with middle in $\left[\dfrac 12,0\right]$ with radius $\dfrac12$ (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y+%2B+sqrt%28x-x%5E2%29+%3D+0) but my solution is draw as parabola (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x-1%2F2%29%5E2-%28y%5E2%29+%3D+1%2F4). What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: In going from your third line to your fourth line, you have $(y + z)^2 = y^2 + z^2$, which is false.

Comment: Yeah, a circle equation (ellipse, really) will be of the form: $a (x-h)^2 + b (y-k)^2 = r^2$ You have: $a (x-h)^2 - b (y-k)^2 = r^2$; a parabola. Pure circle equation will be of the form: $(x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2 = r^2$.

Comment: In the equation of a parabola, only one of the variables is squared.

Comment: Thank you, I'm totally blind...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: $y$ on the other side, then square both sides. Your solution is incorrect, because $(a+b)^2\neq a^2+b^2$.